# Complex Gaussian Integral - $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-p(t+c)^2}dt = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{p}}$?

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis

I found some formulas on books, especially the complex gaussian integral formula:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-p(t+c)^2}dt = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{p}}
$$
for $p,c\in\mathbb C$.
Then if $p=i=\sqrt{-1}$, the integral may have two different values, since $\sqrt{i}
$ has two different values on the complex plane.
Then how can I justify the above integral formula?

Comment: Are you sure that the integral converges for $p=i$? Am I missing something here?

Comment: @karvens For $p=i$ you will get Fresnel-like integrals since $e^{ix^2}=\cos x^2+i\sin x^2$.

Comment: Well, according to wolframalpha, $p=i$ results in the integral taking the principle value of $\sqrt{i}$.

Answer (score -1):

That is true when $p$ has positive real part. For $p$ with non-positive real part, the integral diverges.

For real $c$, the [proof](http://www.physics.sdsu.edu/~johnson/phys410/extra_gauss.pdf) of the real Gaussian integral still largely works.

For $p$ with non-zero real part, a case can be made to choose the square root with positive real part, based on the analycity of $ f(z) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-zu^2} du $ around the positive real semi-axis.
Purely imaginary $p$ is more [complicated](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1903341/integration-of-int-0-infty-e-itw-dt?noredirect=1&lq=1).

For non-real $c$, the [Fourier transform of the Gaussian](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierTransformGaussian.html) gives the same result. Showing that the derivative with respect to $c$ is zero should also work.

Comment: Answers on MSE should be as self-contained as possible, and with an eye towards semi-permanence.  I notice that two of your links are off-site, which means that they could someday suffer from linkrot.  Could you please take a few minutes to discuss (in your answer) the relevant details found on the linked pages?