# Integration of $\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-itw} dt$

Tags: contour-integration, distribution-theory, dirac-delta, fourier-transform

We know that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-itw}dt=2\pi\delta(w)$, but how to calculate the half integration $\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-itw}dt$?

Comment: can you say something about the variables?

Comment: Related recent [thread](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1851922/integration-of-an-improper-integral-and-the-cauchy-principal-value).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-i\omega t}\,dt$ diverges as either a Lebesgue integral or improper Riemann integral.  However, for every "suitable" (smooth with compact support) test function $f(\omega)$, we have

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{L\to \infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\omega)\left(\int_{-L}^L e^{-i\omega t}\,dt\right)\,d\omega&=\lim_{L\to \infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\omega)\,\frac{2\sin(\omega L)}{\omega}\,d\omega\\\\
&=2\pi f(0)
\end{align}$$

Therefore, we can interpret the symbol "$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-i\omega t}\,dt$" to be the regularization of the Dirac Delta

$$\lim_{L\to \infty}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-L}^L e^{-i\omega t}\,dt\sim  \delta(\omega)$$

which is interpreted to mean

$$\lim_{L\to \infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\omega)\left(\int_{-L}^L e^{-i\omega t}\,dt\right)\,d\omega =2\pi f(0)$$

Now, applying the regularization $\lim_{L\to \infty}\int_{0}^L e^{-i\omega t}\,dt$ to a suitable test function reveals

$$\begin{align}
\lim_{L\to \infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\omega)\left(\int_{0}^L e^{-i\omega t}\,dt\right)\,d\omega&=\lim_{L\to \infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\omega)\,\left(\frac{\sin(\omega L)}{\omega}-i\,\frac{1-\cos(\omega L)}{\omega}\right)\,d\omega\\\\
&=\pi f(0)-i\lim_{L\to \infty}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\omega)\,\frac{1-\cos(\omega L)}{\omega}\,d\omega \tag 1\\\\
&=\pi f(0)-i\text{PV}\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{f(\omega)}{\omega}\,d\omega\right)
\end{align}$$

where $\text{PV}$ denotes that [Cauchy-Principal Value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value#Formulation). Note that we used the [Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma#Statement) assuming that $\frac{f(\omega)}{\omega}$ is smooth and of compact support for  $|\omega| \ge\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon >0$ to evaluate the integral on the right-hand side of $(1)$.

Therefore, we can write

$$\lim_{L\to \infty}\int_{0}^L e^{-i\omega t}\,dt\sim \pi \delta(\omega)+ \text{PV}\left(\frac{-i}{\omega}\right)$$

---

Comment: Thank you so much! Your answer is really what I want to know!

Comment: @zito You're welcome!  My pleasure.  -Mark

Answer (score 2):

The integral 
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-itw}dt
$$ 
doesn't exist in the normal functional sense. So it's pretty much the same as in the case of $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-itw}dt=2\pi\delta(w)$, where you already (maybe implicitly) applied the distributional interpretation.

However, where you can see 
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-itw}dt=2\pi\delta(w)
$$
as the Fourier transform of the constant function $f(x)=1$, you can see 
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-itw}dt
$$
as the Fourier transform of the Heaviside function $H(x)=\begin{cases}1,x>0\\0,x<0\end{cases}$. As a result you'll get
$$
\hat{H}(w)=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-itw}dt=\pi\delta(w)+\frac 1{i w}
$$
for a detailed derivation and further references I recommend you for example [this](https://www.cs.uaf.edu/~bueler/M611heaviside.pdf) and of course this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73922/fourier-transform-of-unit-step).

Comment: Thank you so much! It is helpful to consider the integral as the Fourier transform of the Heaviside function.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> Hereafter,
>   $\ds{\Theta\pars{t} =
> \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\expo{\ic\nu t} \over \nu - \ic 0^{+}}
> \,{\dd\nu \over 2\pi\ic}}$ is the *Heaviside Step Function*.

\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-\ic wt}\,\dd t} & =
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Theta\pars{t}\expo{-\ic wt}\,\dd t =
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\bracks{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{\expo{\ic\nu t} \over \nu - \ic 0^{+}}\,{\dd\nu \over 2\pi\ic}}
\expo{-\ic wt}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
-\ic\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{1 \over \nu - \ic 0^{+}}
\bracks{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
\expo{\ic\pars{\nu - w}t}\,{\dd t \over 2\pi}}\,\dd\nu =
-\ic\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\delta\pars{\nu - w} \over \nu - \ic 0^{+}}\,\dd\nu
\\[5mm] & =
-\ic\,{1 \over w - \ic 0^{+}} =
\color{#f00}{-\ic\,\mrm{P.V.}\pars{1 \over w} + \pi\delta\pars{w}}
\end{align}
The result must be understood 'under the integral sign'. Namely,
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\mrm{f}\pars{w}\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-\ic wt}
\,\dd t\,\dd w =
-\ic\,\mrm{P.V.}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\mrm{f}\pars{w} \over w}\,\dd w +
\pi\mrm{f}\pars{0}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: maybe you can show symmetry- think of euler's identity

Comment: This does not help ... at all.